# python : read text file, extract data

Tags: python

Please I am very new to python,
I am trying to create a python file that run in the command line :

```
myscript.py hosts.txt tag

for example:
 if tag = Test 
 return wsgwtestmg.mass.gov
 if tag = QA
 return wsgwaltmg.mass.gov

hosts.txt :

    Test :  wsgwtestmg.mass.gov
    QA : wsgwaltmg.mass.gov
```

myscript.py :

```
 import sys

    def readArgument():
    print('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
    identifier = str(sys.argv[1])
    hostTag = str(sys.argv[2])
    extractURLhost(identifier,hostTag)

    def extractURLhost(idt,tag):
    print(idt)
    with open(idt) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
        print(content)

    readArgument()
```

My result is :

```
Number of arguments: 3 arguments.
hosts.txt

['Test :  wsgwtestmg.mass.gov\n', 'QA : wsgwaltmg.mass.gov\n']
```

Is what I am doing right? Or there is other simple way to do the same ?

How to extract the url using the third argument?

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, ask a question?

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to make a dictionary from the text file, and get your result from that dictionary. Like this:

```
from sys import argv
with open(argv[1]) as f:
    addresses = {i.split(" : ")[0] : i.split(" : ")[1] for i in f}
print(addresses[argv[2]])
```

Comment: Thanks ddsnowboard, it works, wow python is very powerful. Thanks lot

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

with open('hosts.txt') as f:
    print {x.split(' : ')[0].lower(): x.split(' : ')[1] for x in f.read().splitlines()}.get(sys.argv[1:][0].lower(), 'No host found')
```